# npx react-native init does nothing

Tags: node.js, react-native

All of a sudden, none of the commands following `npx react-native` are working, I tried to create a new project using `npx react-native init myapp`, but after pressing enter, nothing happens, no error, nothing, I tried the following commands and same result for all of them, "nothing".

```
npx react-native init myapp
npx react-native init myapp --verbose
npx react-native init myapp --template react-native-template-typescript
npx react-native init myapp --version 0.69.6 --template react-native-template-typescript
```

I'm using `nvm` for node installation and following are my paths:

```
which node -> /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node
which npm -> /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm
which npx -> /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npx
```

It is quite weird, every command gets kinda stuck if its pre is `npx react-native` or `react-native`. I tried to get the version of react-native-cli using `npx react-native --version` or `react-native --version`, same thing, it gets stuck, meaning nothing happens.

My `.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/ndk/21.4.7075529
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm
```

I have tried re-installing `react-native-cli` globally as mentioned in github/SO but none worked.

I seriously have no idea what is going on here. It would be really helpful if someone could guide me!

Thank you in advance!

(If you need any more info that I have not mentioned, please ask for it and I'll try to provide it)

**EDIT-1**

An update, my other terminal window was open in another project's directory and there when I use `npx react-native --version` or any `npx react-native ...` commands, it works, meaning, it is working locally? and not globally? but why? shouldn't `npx` take care of it? I am not able to create new projects in any other directory, the `npx react-native ...` commands are not working outside of that already existing project's directory.

Answer (score 0):

npx executes the npm package directly from the npm registry.

If you use npm -g, it is used from your local machine.
You are using nvm. You need to install it everytime you use a new node version.

If you get something like "command not found", after installing globally and executing. Open a new terminal and try again.

To be sure everything is working correctly with your npm cache execute:

````
npm cache verify
```
````